# Liferay and JSF2 + Spring integration

Tags: spring, jsf, liferay, portlet

I created a new project with Eclipse > Liferay Project > Portlet > JSF 2.x > Primefaces. Then I' m trying to add Spring Bean management to it, by following this [demo](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-faces/tree/3.1.3-ga4/demos/bridge/jsf2-spring-portlet).  
 
The problem is when deploying to tomcat 7 the generated portlet raises a exception.

> Source Document: jndi:/localhost/jsf-test-portlet/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml
>     Cause: Class 'org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver' is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/access/el/SpringBeanELResolver

If i look into the project 'lib' directory, the jars are in place, the same in the generated WAR. So I don't know where the problem may be originated.

---

My ivy.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ivy-module
version="2.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd"
>
<info module="portlet_primefaces_tmpl" organisation="com.liferay" />

<dependencies defaultconf="default">
    <dependency name="el-api" org="javax.el" rev="2.2" />
    <dependency name="jboss-el" org="org.jboss.el" rev="2.0.1.GA" />
    <dependency name="jsf-api" org="com.sun.faces" rev="2.1.21" />
    <dependency name="jsf-impl" org="com.sun.faces" rev="2.1.21" />
    <dependency name="liferay-faces-bridge-api" org="com.liferay.faces" rev="3.1.3-ga4" />
    <dependency name="liferay-faces-bridge-impl" org="com.liferay.faces" rev="3.1.3-ga4" />
    <dependency name="liferay-faces-portal" org="com.liferay.faces" rev="3.1.3-ga4" />
    <dependency name="liferay-faces-util" org="com.liferay.faces" rev="3.1.3-ga4" />
    <dependency name="primefaces" org="org.primefaces" rev="3.5" />
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-core" rev="3.2.1.RELEASE"/>
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-web" rev="3.2.1.RELEASE" />
</dependencies>
```

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/portlet-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Prevent direct access to Facelet view XHTML by the userAgent (browser). -->
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Facelet View XHTML</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>nobody</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-role>
    <role-name>nobody</role-name>
</security-role>
```

My faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<faces-config version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd">

<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>com.liferay.faces.util.lifecycle.DebugPhaseListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
<application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>
```

Comment: If you download the war for the [jsf2-spring-portlet](https://www.liferay.com/community/liferay-projects/liferay-faces/demos#jsf2-spring-portlet) demo and deploy it in your $LIFERAY_HOME/deploy folder, then does it work in your tomcat environment?

Comment: I did what you suggested and it works perfect with that WAR (I can see the Job Application form). But mine still have that problem (exception) at deployment time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analyzing the WAR from the demo, I realized that there are 7 Spring JARS in it, 
I added those remaining dependencies to my `ivy.xml` file, then a "clean/deploy" and now it's working. Maybe not all JARS are required but that's the next step, remove those unnecessary.

My `ivy.xml` now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ivy-module
version="2.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd"
>

<info module="portlet_primefaces_tmpl" organisation="com.liferay" />

<dependencies defaultconf="default">
    <dependency name="jboss-el" org="org.jboss.el" rev="2.0.1.GA" />
    <dependency name="jsf-api" org="com.sun.faces" rev="2.1.21" />
    <dependency name="jsf-impl" org="com.sun.faces" rev="2.1.21" />
    <dependency name="liferay-faces-bridge-api" org="com.liferay.faces" rev="3.1.3-ga4" />
    <dependency name="liferay-faces-bridge-impl" org="com.liferay.faces" rev="3.1.3-ga4" />
    <dependency name="liferay-faces-portal" org="com.liferay.faces" rev="3.1.3-ga4" />
    <dependency name="liferay-faces-util" org="com.liferay.faces" rev="3.1.3-ga4" />
    <dependency name="primefaces" org="org.primefaces" rev="3.5" />
    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency name="spring-core" org="org.springframework" rev="3.0.7.RELEASE"/>
    <dependency name="spring-web" org="org.springframework" rev="3.0.7.RELEASE" />
    <dependency name="spring-context" org="org.springframework" rev="3.0.7.RELEASE" />
    <dependency name="spring-beans" org="org.springframework" rev="3.0.7.RELEASE" />
    <dependency name="spring-expression" org="org.springframework" rev="3.0.7.RELEASE" />
    <dependency name="spring-aop" org="org.springframework" rev="3.0.7.RELEASE" />
    <dependency name="spring-asm" org="org.springframework" rev="3.0.7.RELEASE" />
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working :) Note that the jsf2-spring-portlet demo uses Maven for managing dependencies. The [pom.xml](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-faces/blob/3.1.x/demos/bridge/jsf2-spring-portlet/pom.xml#L41) descriptor only references spring-web as a dependency. All other Spring related JAR dependencies are transitive and so they are included automatically. Ivy has the ability to download/include transitive dependencies too so I'm not sure why you have to list them separately.

Comment: Interesting note about transitive dependencies. I'm creating a project from scratch like described in the question and the JSF2.X project generated comes with IVY. Is there another option easy to set up or "ready to use" like the Eclipse/IVY way? I would really like developing portlets with Maven instead IVY for instance.

Comment: The new [Liferay IDE 2.0 M2](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/1071674/Liferay+IDE+1.x+-+2.0+Upgrade+steps) release will let you create projects for Ant+Ivy or Maven. If you select Maven, then it automatically knows which [Liferay Faces Maven Archetype](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.liferay.maven.archetypes%22) to use.

Comment: Thank you Neil for your help, I'll check it out ;)